Why doesn't IntelliJ IDEA open the Java project in WSL2?
I'm using WSL2 + Windows 11 + IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2024.2.2 + Gateway 2024.2.1.
I have a Java project in WSL2, and when I try to open it using Gateway, its status shows as "running," but the project doesn't open in IntelliJ IDEA. Additionally, IDEA doesn't display any window.
However, when I open a Rust project in Gateway, it correctly opens in JetBrains RustRover.
Why doesn't IntelliJ IDEA open the Java project in WSL2?
I have deleted the folder
.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2/
.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-IU/

then I tried to open the java project again, but when it finished downloading some dependencies and start the IDEA in WSL2, still nothing happens.
Here are some logs when I clicked to open the project.
idea.log in WSL2 .cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/log/idea.log
2024-09-25 10:46:25,603 [4103205]   INFO - #c.i.p.i.b.ApplicationLoader - External instance command received
2024-09-25 10:46:25,603 [4103205]   INFO - #c.i.i.CommandLineProcessor - External command line:
Dir: /mnt/c/Users/John
cwmHostStatus
/home/farwind/workspace/halo
--writeJson
/tmp/cwmHostStatus3596995998
-----
2024-09-25 10:46:25,603 [4103205]   INFO - #c.i.i.CommandLineProcessor - Processing command with com.jetbrains.rdserver.unattendedHost.UnattendedHostStatusStarterLegacy@4b6606d6
2024-09-25 10:46:25,603 [4103205]   WARN - #c.j.r.u.UnattendedHostStatusStarter - Command cwmHostStatus is depreated. Use remoteDevStatus instead
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - #c.j.r.P.H - Get RD links
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - #c.j.r.u.UnattendedHostStatusStarter - STATUS:
{
  "appPid": 8641,
  "appVersion": "IU-242.22855.74",
  "runtimeVersion": "21.0.3b509.15",
  "unattendedMode": true,
  "backendUnresponsive": false,
  "modalDialogIsOpened": false,
  "idePath": "/home/farwind/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2",
  "ideIdentityString": "/home/farwind/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2",
  "joinLink": "tcp://127.0.0.1:5990#jt=11fc83aa-8aee-42d9-a86d-101ae828ed45&p=IU&fp=FCE5D75626DCC6DB653B259D354583CCAC1B21B2BEB11ED4906EFEA028A8577E&cb=242.22855.74&newUi=true&jb=21.0.3b509.15",
  "httpLink": "https://code-with-me.jetbrains.com/remoteDev#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
  "gatewayLink": "jetbrains-gateway://connect#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
  "projects": [
    {
      "projectName": "halo",
      "projectPath": "/home/farwind/workspace/halo",
      "dateLastOpened": 1727232385604,
      "joinLink": "tcp://127.0.0.1:5990#jt=11fc83aa-8aee-42d9-a86d-101ae828ed45&p=IU&fp=FCE5D75626DCC6DB653B259D354583CCAC1B21B2BEB11ED4906EFEA028A8577E&cb=242.22855.74&newUi=true&jb=21.0.3b509.15",
      "httpLink": "https://code-with-me.jetbrains.com/remoteDev#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
      "gatewayLink": "jetbrains-gateway://connect#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
      "controllerConnected": false,
      "secondsSinceLastControllerActivity": 4098,
      "backgroundTasksRunning": false,
      "users": [
        "farwind"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT - STATUS:
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT - {
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "appPid": 8641,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "appVersion": "IU-242.22855.74",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "runtimeVersion": "21.0.3b509.15",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "unattendedMode": true,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "backendUnresponsive": false,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "modalDialogIsOpened": false,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "idePath": "/home/farwind/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/c37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "ideIdentityString": "/home/farwind/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "joinLink": "tcp://127.0.0.1:5990#jt=11fc83aa-8aee-42d9-a86d-101ae828ed45&p=IU&fp=FCE5D75626DCC6DB653B259D354583CCAC1B21B2BEB11ED4906EFEA028A8577E&cb=242.22855.74&newUi=true&jb=21.0.3b509.15",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,604 [4103206]   INFO - STDOUT -   "httpLink": "https://code-with-me.jetbrains.com/remoteDev#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -   "gatewayLink": "jetbrains-gateway://connect#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -   "projects": [
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -     {
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "projectName": "halo",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "projectPath": "/home/farwind/workspace/halo",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "dateLastOpened": 1727232385604,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "joinLink": "tcp://127.0.0.1:5990#jt=11fc83aa-8aee-42d9-a86d-101ae828ed45&p=IU&fp=FCE5D75626DCC6DB653B259D354583CCAC1B21B2BEB11ED4906EFEA028A8577E&cb=242.22855.74&newUi=true&jb=21.0.3b509.15",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "httpLink": "https://code-with-me.jetbrains.com/remoteDev#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "gatewayLink": "jetbrains-gateway://connect#idePath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2F.cache%2FJetBrains%2FRemoteDev%2Fdist%2Fc37955a7f3f02_ideaIU-2024.2.2&projectPath=%2Fhome%2Ffarwind%2Fworkspace%2Fhalo&host=MY-ASUS-PC&port=22&user=farwind&type=ssh&deploy=false&newUi=true",
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "controllerConnected": false,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "secondsSinceLastControllerActivity": 4098,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "backgroundTasksRunning": false,
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       "users": [
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -         "farwind"
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -       ]
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -     }
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT -   ]
2024-09-25 10:46:25,605 [4103207]   INFO - STDOUT - }
2024-09-25 10:46:26,146 [4103748]   INFO - #c.i.p.i.b.ApplicationLoader - External instance command received
2024-09-25 10:46:26,146 [4103748]   INFO - #c.i.i.CommandLineProcessor - External command line:
Dir: /mnt/c/Users/John
cwmHostStatus
/home/farwind/workspace/halo
--writeJson
/tmp/cwmHostStatus2518174774
-----
2024-09-25 10:46:26,146 [4103748]   INFO - #c.i.i.CommandLineProcessor - Processing command with com.jetbrains.rdserver.unattendedHost.UnattendedHostStatusStarterLegacy@4b6606d6
2024-09-25 10:46:26,146 [4103748]   WARN - #c.j.r.u.UnattendedHostStatusStarter - Command cwmHostStatus is depreated. Use remoteDevStatus instead
2024-09-25 10:46:26,147 [4103749]   INFO - #c.j.r.P.H - Get RD links

.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-IU/_home_farwind_workspace_halo/log/stderr.log
2024-09-25 10:46:25,603 [4103205]   WARN - #c.j.r.u.UnattendedHostStatusStarter - Command cwmHostStatus is depreated. Use remoteDevStatus instead
2024-09-25 10:46:26,146 [4103748]   WARN - #c.j.r.u.UnattendedHostStatusStarter - Command cwmHostStatus is depreated. Use remoteDevStatus instead


As a test, are you able to open the same project from local IDE? Does it help by reinstalling the backend side DIE with the latest release?
